# How can I update and specific nested struct field in MongoDB with golang using bson

Tags: mongodb, go

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

`bson.M{constants.MONGO_SET: entity.UserShop{Shop.ID: userShop.Shop.ID}}`

instead using

`bson.M{constants.MONGO_SET: entity.UserShop{"shop._id": userShop.Shop.ID}}`

being

```
type UserShop struct {
  User `json:"-"  bson:"-"`
  Shop `json:"shop,omitempty"  bson:"shop,omitempty"`
}
```

and shop

```
type Shop struct {
    ID          primitive.ObjectID `json:"-" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Name        string             `json:"name,omitempty" bson:"name,omitempty"`
    Description string             `json:"description,omitempty" bson:"description,omitempty"`
    ImageURL    string             `json:"imageURL,omitempty" bson:"imageURL,omitempty"`
    Stars       int64              `json:"stars,omitempty" bson:"stars,omitempty"`
    // Location    *[]int64           `json:"location,omitempty" bson:"location,omitmepty"`
    // Products    *AllProducts       `json:"products,omitempty" bson:"products,omitempty"`
}
```

In database struct :

Shop:{
_id: "12344",
name: "hello"
}

I want to modify any specific field and do not modify any other field inside shop object

Answer (score 0):

Use the following expression to update only the `shop._id` field:

```
bson.M{"$set":bson.M{"shop._id":userShop.Shop.ID}}
```

Comment: I just want to avoid using "shop._id" string, wondering if theres is a way to achieve the same behaviour using the given struct.

Comment: The given struct has an int64 field which will always be added to the expression. You can define a separate struct containing only the _id field if you want.